how to manage size of /home .cache and .local folders

running RHEL 8.10 x86-64 on a server with many users,
/home is on a separate partition, and all user accounts as defined in /etc/passwd have their account under /home but there is a separate /data partition where all data actually is and where work happens in and out of.  Nobody does anything under the /home/<account> folder and I had hoped that each user account folder would never grow above 1Mb.  Most accounts are in the Kb range.
for those that VNC in and run various software, over time we observe their /home/<account> folder growing into 1+ GB range.  It is their .local and .cache and .mozilla folders that are the offenders.

What is a way to manage this?
This is on a server with 100+ users, most of which only make use of a samba data share however this does become a disk space problem for the 10-20 users that VNC in and run stuff.  XFS_quota is enabled on all /home accounts but this is not a solution in terms of data management and keeping things functional, it just amounts to 20 user accounts folders under /home being  1.0Gb in size with their .cache and .local folders being huge.
Is it safe to make an /etc/profile.d/custom.sh that does a rm -rf ~/.cache/* that deletes the contents every time a user logs in ?
